# Replacing Heading (<h1>, <h2> ...) Tags with <p> Tags and Classes

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, wysiwyg

I wish to replace  tags from a WYSIWYG editor to .

At the moment I am using the following code to achieve this.

```
$content = preg_replace('/<h1(.*?)<\/h1>/si', '<p class="heading-1"$1</p>', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<h2(.*?)<\/h2>/si', '<p class="heading-2"$1</p>', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<h3(.*?)<\/h3>/si', '<p class="heading-3"$1</p>', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<h4(.*?)<\/h4>/si', '<p class="heading-4"$1</p>', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<h5(.*?)<\/h5>/si', '<p class="heading-5"$1</p>', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/<h6(.*?)<\/h6>/si', '<p class="heading-6"$1</p>', $content);
```

As you can see this code is quite messy, it would be great if I could condense this into a single regular expression but I simply lack the ability to do so.

I had considered this line of code as an alternative.

```
$content = preg_replace('/<h(.*?)<\/h(.*?)>/si', '<p class="heading-$2"$1</p>', $content);
```

I'm not sure about using the above, clients have a tendency to copy content from other sites, paste it straight into their new WYSIWYG and i've seen anything from hr tags to heading tags popping in there.

What I require is simply the above single line, except the tag itself can only be 2 specific characters (So ensure the tag starts with a H and is followed by [1-6]).

I also require that the class it adds to the p tag is specific to the number use, eg: heading-1, heading-2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: `$content = preg_replace('/<h([1-6])(.*?)<\/h1>/si', '<p class="heading-$1"$2</p>', $content);` Have fun.

Comment: Surely that won't work as it expects a finishing </h1> tag?

Comment: and [here](http://regex101.com/r/nT6yF8)'s how you may do it. With this regex, `<h3> hello world</h4>` won't get matched.

Comment: That's great, thanks for your help.

I am now using this, A slightly modified version of your original as I believe i'm correct in saying it expects a correct finishing tag?

$content = preg_replace('/<h([1-6])(.*?)<\/h([1-6])>/si', '<p class="heading-$1"$2</p>', $content);

Comment: Well to be honest, you should use an HTML parser. But if you're confident of the input you might get then go ahead using regex.

Comment: You'll have to excuse my lack of knowledge, but would there be performance differences in a HTML parser for multiple WYSIWYG editors?

Comment: Performance doesn't really matter here since we're talking about microseconds. One should then go for a readable and maintanable code along with a trusted way. If the format breaks up a little, your regex will fail. Thus HTML parsers are the best solution in your case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$content = <<<HTML
<h1 class="heading-title">test1</h1>
<H2 class="green">test2</H2>
<h5 class="red">test</h5>
<h5 class="">test test</h5>
HTML;

$content = preg_replace('#<h([1-6]).*?class="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/h[1-6]>#si', '<p class="heading-${1} ${2}">${3}</p>', $content);

echo htmlentities($content);
```

**Result:**

```
<p class="heading-1 heading-title">test1</p> 
<p class="heading-2 green">test2</p> 
<p class="heading-5 red">test</p> 
<p class="heading-5 ">test test</p>
```

**Note for existing classes:**
Even if your element doesn't have an existing class you have to add empty class attribute `class=""`. Instead this will not work as expected. :( Better solution is to use **[preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)**. Then you can check if a match exists and create your `p tags` more accurately.

Comment: `{1}` doesn't add anything to your regex, so just remove it.

Comment: That works great, except it does not respect existing classes on the heading tag? I am now using:

`$content = preg_replace('/<h([1-6])(.*?)<\/h([1-6])>/si', '<p class="heading-$1"$2</p>', $content);`

But this too doesn't respect existing classes.

Comment: Of course it will not. Why you need the existing class? It will not fit for the `p tag` probably. Anyway, I will edit to add the existing class, too.

Comment: Sorry, I now see why existing classes would be a very difficult task. But maybe there are other existing attributes that need keeping? I'm just looking for the best solution to my problem, if this is as far as I can take this task then that is fine. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: I think this is the best way to do it now

`preg_replace('/<h([1-6])(.*?)<\/h([1-6])>/si', '<p class="heading-$1"$2</p>', $content);`

It doesn't merge clases, but it will respect and keep any other attributes on the element.

Comment: Is there no way of making the entire 'class=""' section optional? It's so close! I've tried adding brackets around it followed by a ? but i'm not entirely sure what i'm doing.

Comment: You can try with `preg_replace_callback` but it will be much complicated. Another option is to use 2 different `preg_replace`s: one for these with a class and one for these without a class. But then you will have a little code ducplication. :(

Comment: Can someone advise how can i do same for C#

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = <<<HTML
<h1 style="heading-title" attr="attr" label="label">test1</h1>
<h1>test</h1>
<H2 style="heading-title"  class="green">test2</H2>
<h5 style="heading-title"  class="red">test</h5>
<h2 style="bbb"  class="a" style="dazd-title" >test</h2>
HTML;

$content = \preg_replace('#<h([1-6])\s*((?:(?!class).)*?)>(.*?)</h[1-6]>#si', '<p class="heading-${1}" ${2}><span style="color: #e03e2d">${3}</span></p>', $content);
$content = \preg_replace('#<h([1-6])(.*?)class="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/h[1-6]>#si', '<p  ${2} class="heading-${1} ${3}" ${4}><span style="color: #e03e2d">${5}</span></p>', $content);
    echo ($content);
```

Result:

```
<p class="heading-1" style="heading-title" attr="attr" label="label">test1</p>
<p class="heading-1" >test</p>
<p class="heading-2 green">test2</p>
<p class="heading-5 red">test</p>
<p class="heading-2 ">test</p>
```