# preg_replace headings with strong

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace all headings (h1, h2, h3 etc.) from a text with a regex, but it only replace the first opening tag and the last one.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$regex = '/<h(?:[\d]{1})(?:[^>]*)>([^<].*)<\/h(?:[\d]{1})>/mi';
$str = '<h1 class="text-align-center" style="font-size:22px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:IntroBold, sans-serif;line-height:1.5;letter-spacing:0px;font-weight:700;text-align:center;">You should be&nbsp;confident solving wicked problems in a hybrid role between strategy, research, design and business&nbsp;through a discovery driven approach.&nbsp;</h1><p></p><h2 style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:.5em;font-family:IntroBold, sans-serif;font-size:19px;line-height:1em;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;font-weight:700;"><strong>KEY RESPONSIBILITIES</strong></h2>';
echo preg_replace($regex, '<strong>$1</strong>', $str);
```

The result with this is `<strong>[...]</h1><p></p><h2...>[...]</strong>`, but of course it's wrong.

Comment: It is not recommended to use regex for html parsing. It would be easier to use a html parser to extract the values and put them in new tags (like PHP internal DOMDocument)

Comment: Have a Look at this, May be you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16958776/6730400

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obviously regexp is not the perfect solution for HTML parsing, if you want a safer solution you should find an HTML parser and do it that way.

However this regexp will do a half decent job and will work for the example provided:

`/<h\d.*?>(.*?)<\/h\d>/ims`

[Proof](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jRV).

Comment: It works for the first heading, but the content of <h2> there isn't in the second strong: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jRN

Comment: Good catch, @Grork, I have updated the regular expression with a fix. Proof: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/jRO

Comment: This regex is overly complicated. `(?:[\d]{1})` can be `\d`. The `(?:.*?)` can just be `.*?`. The `m` modifier isn't doing anything. http://regexr.com/3fqh9

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alternative as [simple_dom_html](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

You can do vast things using this including your concern too.,

Here how you can achieve :

```
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
foreach($dom->find("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5") as $e)
            $e->outertext = "<strong>".$e->innertext."";
```

I am replacing all header tags with strong.
You can have your inline css if you want too.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much performance-wise path to match headings:

```
<h(\d)[^>]*>([^<]*(<(?!\/h\1)[^<]*)*)<\/h\1>
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/fel5cX/1)

* Engine finds matches in 61 steps while with provided regex in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43585972/1020526), engine needs to take too many steps ([1193 steps](https://regex101.com/r/cO0aL4/1)) to match the same parts.

### Right way:

Although Regular Expressions seem handy most of the time, it's a good practice to have the right tool for the right job: [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

```
$dom = new domdocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new domxpath($dom);
$headings = $xpath->query("//h1 | //h2 | //h3 | //h4 | //h5 | //h6");
foreach ($headings as $h) {
    $s = $dom->createElement("strong", $h->nodeValue);
    $h->parentNode->replaceChild($s, $h);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[PHP live demo](https://3v4l.org/r7jIP)